# /etc/cron.daily/apt: Segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, cron, apt, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-10.10

I have a system that I set up with Maverick and the "automatically apply security updates" setting.  It is now sending e-mail on a daily basis:

```
Subject: Anacron job 'cron.daily' on gwen

/etc/cron.daily/apt:
Segmentation fault
```

If I manually "apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade", it runs just fine.  Also, if I login and run /etc/cron.daily/apt it also does not give the segfault.

I did some searches on google and most of the results seem to be from 2008 and related to "pam_mount", which is not on this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in the python-apt library, documented in [Ubuntu bug 664514](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-apt/+bug/664514).  Upstream has released a bug-fix, but Ubuntu hasn't assigned this to anyone to fix.  [More information and interim packages which fix this problem until Ubuntu releases a fix](http://www.tummy.com/journals/entries/jafo_20101203_060502).

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting your problem stems from insufficient environment variables in that apt script.  (eg:  $PATH or $LD_LIBRARY_PATH) Essentially, there's a difference between running things via cron and running them in an interactive shell.  The latter gets your login environment from places like /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc.  Try adding a line or two at the start /etc/cron.daily/apt to import those settings, like so:
`. /etc/profile`

I'll be totally honest, and point out that I'm not too familiar with Ubunto, so those file locations may not be perfect.  If you're using a shell other than Bash, your personal login file may be ~/.profile, or ~/.cshrc, or even something completely different.  But the concept is the same.

A related question can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/95729/difference-of-running-scripts-manually-or-with-a-cronjob).


--Christopher Karel

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I agree that it seems like it's a safe bet that it's either something in the environment or related to running without a controlling terminal.  A couple of notes: This cron job is something provided by Ubuntu and is meant to be running from cron, but I'll take a look at whether sourcing /etc/profile might help.    When I login, I don't have any LD_* variables set.  Under 10.04 this cron job definitely does work, so it's something with the job or the commands it calls in 10.10.  I've put some debugging in place so I can see WHERE it fails tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: Turns out that the reason I couldn't reproduce it from the command-line is that the script doesn't run all the components, depending on how recently it was run from cron.